# Android library resources in JAR

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-library

I'm trying to write an Android class library project. At first I tried to reference the project but got ClassDefNotFound error. So what I did was to take the JAR file from my library project output and put in in my project. Now I'm not getting the class not found but I get an error that it can't find resources (the library has string, styles, anims...).

```
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.popupdialog.R$style
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at com.mycompany.popupdialog.Popupdialog.<init>(SweetAlertDialog.java:75)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at com.mycompany.popupdialog.Popupdialog.<init>(SweetAlertDialog.java:71)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at com.mycompany.androidApplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:156)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-30 02:27:00.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I have all the resources I need in the JAR file without having to include them in the hosting project?

In the case of referencing to a project - I tried doing everything I found online about cleaning the projects, setting the project in Order & Export screen - nothing helped.

Comment: please add your jar to build path

Comment: @ravi did that (as mentioned above added it to eclipse Order & Export)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem behind this is, you are just putting your library jar in your `lib` folder but not attaching to `BuildPath`.

try this

> right click on jar you have attached.
>
> goto BuildPath ,
>
> click on add to BuildPath.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

1. I think your Android Menifests File package name is not correct,
   just Check it your package name same as entry of menifest file package name.
2. Rebuild your project. and clean it.
3. Restart your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Eclipse, you would need to add the library to the current work space then reference it. See this reference link: [1]

---

To get your resources with your android application from a separate module you will need to grab the compiled .aar file in your **outputs/build/aar** folder. Drop it in your libs folder then reference to it by doing the following:[2]

1) Add the following to your repository block in build.gradle so that it looks something like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

2) You now reference it in your dependencies!:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.kevinpelgrims.library:library:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

[1] http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

[2] http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project/

Comment: I'm not using maven. I'm using eclipse. And all my projects are built localy.

Comment: In this case, you might need to import your library into the same workspace then add a reference to it, see: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I've updated the initial answer for visibility.